# Second method is not returning an error but will not work. Need to know how to use multiple methods in java

Tags: java

I am writing a program that allows the user to select a menu item and then adds that menu item to the total so far I have created a method that will display the menu but my second one will not run. My class is just now getting to methods so I am still learning the basics. Thank you in advance!  Here is the code that I have written so far:

```
// Author : Maya Strickland
//Project Name : MCC Grub & Grill
// Date: 09/27/2022
import java.util.Scanner;
class main {
  
  // List of variables I will use in the following program for each menu item
    static final double smallPizza = 8.99;
    static final double mediumPizza = 11.99;
    static final double largePizza = 14.99;
    static final double veggieBurger = 5.99;
    static final double grilledChickenSandwich = 6.99;
    static final double hamburgerSandwich = 7.99;
    static final double macAndCheese = 2.49;
    static final double handCutFries = 2.75;
    static final double onionRings = 2.99;
    static final double foodTaxRate = 4.125;
    static double total = 0;
    

  static void myMethod()
  {  
    //Welcome Banner for MCC Grub and Grill
    System.out.println("");
    System.out.println("Welcome to MCC Grub and Grill!");
    System.out.println("");
    // Code to tell the user that the list that is next is our current menu items
    System.out.println("Here is a list of our current menu items: ");
    // List of Entree Menu Items Available 
    System.out.println("");
    System.out.println("Entrees: ");
    System.out.println("1. Small Pizza - Perfect size pizza for just one.....$8.99");
    System.out.println("2. Medium Pizza - A pizza big enough to share, or not.....$11.99");
    System.out.println("3. Large Pizza - A pizza big enough for the whole family!.....$14.99");
    System.out.println("4. Veggie Burger - A black bean burger with Tomato, Mayo, Lettuce, and PepperJack Cheese. All grilled on a panini press.....$5.99");
    System.out.println("5. Grilled Chicken Sandwich - Grilled Chicken topped with Tomato, Mayo, Lettuce, PepperJack Cheese. All grilled on a panini press.....$6.99");
    System.out.println("6. Hamburger- Classic 100% beef patty with Tomato, Mayo, Lettuce and PepperJack Cheese. All grilled on a panini press.....$7.99");
    System.out.println("");

    // List of Sides
    System.out.println("Sides: ");
    System.out.println("7. Mac and Cheese - Not your momma's mac! Spicy 3 Cheese Mac made with Red Pepper Flakes. Beware the spice!.....$2.49");
    System.out.println("8. Hand-Cut Fries - Crisp, golden fries deep fried in peanut oil.....$2.75");
    System.out.println("9. Onion Rings - Crisp, golden rings of onion deep fried in peanut oil.....$2.99");
    // End of Menu
    System.out.println("");

  }

public static void main(String[]args)
{
  myMethod();
}
  
static void oneRoundOfOrders()
    {
  System.out.println("Please enter the menu number of the food you would like to order or 0 to stop ordering");
      Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in);
      int menuItem = input.nextInt();
    // Switch statement to select the menu item based on keyboard input into menuItem
      switch (menuItem) {
      case 0:
      System.out.println(total);
        break;
    
      case 1:
        System.out.println("You've chosen small pizza! A perfect size pizza for just one! " + "$" + smallPizza);
        total += smallPizza;
        break;
     
      case 2:
        System.out.println("You've chosen medium pizza! A pizza big enough to share...or not " + "$" + mediumPizza);
        total += mediumPizza;
        break;
      
      case 3:
        System.out.println("You've chosen large pizza. A pizza big enough for the whole family! " + "$" + largePizza);
        total += largePizza;
        break;
      
      case 4:  
      System.out.println ("You've chosen Veggie Burger! A black bean burger with Tomato, Mayo, Lettuce, and PepperJack Cheese. All grilled on a panini press. " + "$" + veggieBurger);
        total += veggieBurger;
        break;
      
      case 5:
        System.out.println("You've chosen Grilled Chicken Sandwich! Grilled Chicken topped with Tomato, Mayo, Lettuce, PepperJack Cheese. All grilled on a panini press " + "$" + grilledChickenSandwich);
        total += grilledChickenSandwich;
        break;
       
      case 6:
        System.out.println("You've chosen a Hamburger! Classic 100% beef patty with Tomato, Mayo, Lettuce and PepperJack Cheese. All grilled on a panini press " + "$" + hamburgerSandwich);
        total += hamburgerSandwich;
        break;
      
      case 7:
        System.out.println("You've chosen Mac and Cheese! Not your momma's mac! Spicy 3 Cheese Mac made with Red Pepper Flakes. Beware the spice! " + "$" + macAndCheese);
        total += macAndCheese;
        break;
      
      case 8:
      System.out.println("You've chosen Hand Cut Fries! Crisp, golden fries deep fried in peanut oil " + "$" + handCutFries);
        total += handCutFries;
        break;
          
      case 9:
        System.out.println("You've chosen Onion Rings! Crisp, golden rings of onion deep fried in peanut oil " + "$" + onionRings);
        total += onionRings;
        break; 
      default:
       System.out.println("Please try again");
      } // end of switch
    } // end of oneRoundOfOrders function
  
public static void main(String[]args)
{
oneRoundOfOrders();  
}

}// end of class
```

Comment: Your code does not compile because it contains the same method twice, namely `public static void main(String[]args)`

Answer (score 0):

This might solve the error you are facing. I can see **more than one main** method in your code to invoke each different method. delete that main method in the end and invoke the second method from the first main method itself. also we don't need to declare the method before method invocation in java.

```
// Author : Maya Strickland
//Project Name : MCC Grub & Grill
// Date: 09/27/2022
import java.util.Scanner;
class main {
  
  // List of variables I will use in the following program for each menu item
    static final double smallPizza = 8.99;
    static final double mediumPizza = 11.99;
    static final double largePizza = 14.99;
    static final double veggieBurger = 5.99;
    static final double grilledChickenSandwich = 6.99;
    static final double hamburgerSandwich = 7.99;
    static final double macAndCheese = 2.49;
    static final double handCutFries = 2.75;
    static final double onionRings = 2.99;
    static final double foodTaxRate = 4.125;
    static double total = 0;
    

  static void myMethod()
  {  
    //Welcome Banner for MCC Grub and Grill
    System.out.println("");
    System.out.println("Welcome to MCC Grub and Grill!");
    System.out.println("");
    // Code to tell the user that the list that is next is our current menu items
    System.out.println("Here is a list of our current menu items: ");
    // List of Entree Menu Items Available 
    System.out.println("");
    System.out.println("Entrees: ");
    System.out.println("1. Small Pizza - Perfect size pizza for just one.....$8.99");
    System.out.println("2. Medium Pizza - A pizza big enough to share, or not.....$11.99");
    System.out.println("3. Large Pizza - A pizza big enough for the whole family!.....$14.99");
    System.out.println("4. Veggie Burger - A black bean burger with Tomato, Mayo, Lettuce, and PepperJack Cheese. All grilled on a panini press.....$5.99");
    System.out.println("5. Grilled Chicken Sandwich - Grilled Chicken topped with Tomato, Mayo, Lettuce, PepperJack Cheese. All grilled on a panini press.....$6.99");
    System.out.println("6. Hamburger- Classic 100% beef patty with Tomato, Mayo, Lettuce and PepperJack Cheese. All grilled on a panini press.....$7.99");
    System.out.println("");

    // List of Sides
    System.out.println("Sides: ");
    System.out.println("7. Mac and Cheese - Not your momma's mac! Spicy 3 Cheese Mac made with Red Pepper Flakes. Beware the spice!.....$2.49");
    System.out.println("8. Hand-Cut Fries - Crisp, golden fries deep fried in peanut oil.....$2.75");
    System.out.println("9. Onion Rings - Crisp, golden rings of onion deep fried in peanut oil.....$2.99");
    // End of Menu
    System.out.println("");

  }

public static void main(String[]args)
{
  myMethod();
  oneRoundOfOrders(); 
}
  
static void oneRoundOfOrders()
    {
  System.out.println("Please enter the menu number of the food you would like to order or 0 to stop ordering");
      Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in);
      int menuItem = input.nextInt();
    // Switch statement to select the menu item based on keyboard input into menuItem
      switch (menuItem) {
      case 0:
      System.out.println(total);
        break;
    
      case 1:
        System.out.println("You've chosen small pizza! A perfect size pizza for just one! " + "$" + smallPizza);
        total += smallPizza;
        break;
     
      case 2:
        System.out.println("You've chosen medium pizza! A pizza big enough to share...or not " + "$" + mediumPizza);
        total += mediumPizza;
        break;
      
      case 3:
        System.out.println("You've chosen large pizza. A pizza big enough for the whole family! " + "$" + largePizza);
        total += largePizza;
        break;
      
      case 4:  
      System.out.println ("You've chosen Veggie Burger! A black bean burger with Tomato, Mayo, Lettuce, and PepperJack Cheese. All grilled on a panini press. " + "$" + veggieBurger);
        total += veggieBurger;
        break;
      
      case 5:
        System.out.println("You've chosen Grilled Chicken Sandwich! Grilled Chicken topped with Tomato, Mayo, Lettuce, PepperJack Cheese. All grilled on a panini press " + "$" + grilledChickenSandwich);
        total += grilledChickenSandwich;
        break;
       
      case 6:
        System.out.println("You've chosen a Hamburger! Classic 100% beef patty with Tomato, Mayo, Lettuce and PepperJack Cheese. All grilled on a panini press " + "$" + hamburgerSandwich);
        total += hamburgerSandwich;
        break;
      
      case 7:
        System.out.println("You've chosen Mac and Cheese! Not your momma's mac! Spicy 3 Cheese Mac made with Red Pepper Flakes. Beware the spice! " + "$" + macAndCheese);
        total += macAndCheese;
        break;
      
      case 8:
      System.out.println("You've chosen Hand Cut Fries! Crisp, golden fries deep fried in peanut oil " + "$" + handCutFries);
        total += handCutFries;
        break;
          
      case 9:
        System.out.println("You've chosen Onion Rings! Crisp, golden rings of onion deep fried in peanut oil " + "$" + onionRings);
        total += onionRings;
        break; 
      default:
       System.out.println("Please try again");
      } // end of switch
    } // end of oneRoundOfOrders function

}// end of class
```

Reference:
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methods.html
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/arguments.html